# How can choose DotNet40 prerequiste at visual studio installer2017?

Tags: visual-studio-2017

How can I choose `.NET framework 4.0` to install , because it only shows  `.NET 3.5/4.5` and other higher versions when I click `prerequisites` button in `Property Pages`??

And I can see those pakages in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\ClickOnce Bootstrapper\Packages` but no `DotNetFX40` folder, so how can I install `DotNetFX40 pakage` in there?

```
ENV: Win10  Visual studio 2017
```

Comment: Well,I sloved this..I found there is a DotNet4 folder in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\SDK\Bootstrapper\Packages after I installed vs2015, and copy that to vs2017'pakages folder and it's done..

Comment: post your comment as answer